# pythonでスラッシュのある部分まで文字列を取り出したい。

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

`video/mp4`この文字列からmp4だけを取り出したいです。
`video/webm`になったりもするのでスラッシュまでの文字列を取り出すプログラムを正規表現が苦手でどう書いていいか分かりません。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

下記でできませんか？

```
aaa = "video/mp4"
bbb = aaa.split('/')
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。上手く行きました！